# External cache directory to bypass Android 10 not being able to execute files on home directory

Tags: java, android, android-file

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10), you cannot run `exec()` on files in the app's home directory in Android 10.

Is there another location (external) that I can save files to and execute from that would not be considered in the app's home directory that would behave the same way as the app's cache directory?